# What are the different ways in which a XSS vulnerability can be exploited?

Tags: xss

I understand that XSS vulnerability can be used to execute a piece of javascript code in the browser of the victim.

One of the obvious ways it can be exploited is if it can be used to compromise cookies of the victim. Maybe even load an iframe which serves malware.

Are there any other ways in which XSS can be exploited?

Comment: Private data could be shipped offsite (if you're on your banking website, perhaps it sends the HTML of your latest account statement to the attacker). Data on the page could be manipulated (imagine showing a billionaire a news article saying one of his largest investments is about to go bankrupt), etc.

Comment: Short said: It runs within the site's scope, so it can do *everything thinkable*, that any script from the site itself could do, e.g. altering form data on submit.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Ah yes, altered form data. XSS on a stock trading website could sell all your Google shares for a dollar. Not fun!

Comment: intercept keystrokes, send data via AJAX or image urls anywhere, load external scrips...

Answer (score 0):

I will answer by citing the **XSS Attack Consequences** section of the [OWASP Cross-site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)#Stored_and_Reflected_XSS_Attacks) article.

> [...] Do not be fooled into thinking that a “read only” or “brochureware” site is not vulnerable to serious reflected XSS attacks. XSS can cause a variety of problems for the end user that range in severity from an annoyance to complete account compromise. The most severe XSS attacks involve disclosure of the user’s session cookie, allowing an attacker to hijack the user’s session and take over the account. Other damaging attacks include the disclosure of end user files, installation of Trojan horse programs, redirect the user to some other page or site, or modify presentation of content. An XSS vulnerability allowing an attacker to modify a press release or news item could affect a company’s stock price or lessen consumer confidence. An XSS vulnerability on a pharmaceutical site could allow an attacker to modify dosage information resulting in an overdose. For more information on these types of attacks see [Content Spoofing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Spoofing).

To answer more specifically to your question, if an attacker can inject javascript into a page. He can also change the DOM, and trick the user into installing malware or propagate fake news.